# Saving plots generated from list using names in list using lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of data tables, each of which contains data in the same format and each of which has a unique name. Example below:

```
> head(list$table1)
        gene     logFC negLogPval
    1   CROT -1.546082   6.405688
    2 CASC15 -1.718302   5.501062
    3  ITGA8 -2.839048   5.159019
    4   LDB2 -1.258781   4.646456
    5  PTGS1  1.009361   3.791273
    6  FABP5 -1.186742   3.189549
```

I want to make a separate plot from each of these data tables in the list and then save, which I can do using the following function:

```
volc = function(input){
  ggplot(input, aes(logFC, negLogPval)) + 
  geom_point()
  ggsave(paste0("Volcano_", names(input), ".png"), device = "png")
}
```

If I run this on a single data table as below:

```
volc(list$table1)
```

Then it generates a plot as expected, but instead of taking the name of the object to name the file, it takes the name of the first column in the data table instead, i.e. saves the file as "Volcano_gene.png" instead of "Volcano_table1.png".

This means that if I run this on my list of data tables using `lapply`, as below:

```
lapply(list, volc)
```

It runs through the code on each of the tables, but saves all of them as "Volcano_gene.png", overwriting the previous table as it goes, meaning the only plot that gets saved is the very last one generated.

I am sure I am missing something simple with the `names()` function, but can anyone help me fix this so that it saves the plots with names as expected?

Comment: If you want some pretty Volcano plots, see [EnhancedVolcano](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/EnhancedVolcano/inst/doc/EnhancedVolcano.html) package.

Comment: Will check it out, I have been playing with colouring my plots with thresholds etc manually, I just left them out of the example code. This might be a simpler method though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you apply your function to each `data.frame` in your `list` then `names(input)` gives you the column names of the `data.frame`. See this example.

```
data(mtcars)
l = list()
l$a = mtcars[, 1:2]
l$b = mtcars[, 2:3]

lapply(l, names)
$a
[1] "mpg" "cyl"

$b
[1] "cyl"  "disp"
```

To resolve this change the function to take a second argument name.

```
volc = function(input, name) {
  ggplot(input, aes(logFC, negLogPval)) + 
  geom_point()
  ggsave(paste0("Volcano_", name, ".png"), device = "png")
}
```

Now you can use `Map` to archieve your goal:

```
Map(volc, list, names(list))
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. I responded to Roland before I read this, but this is a better way of doing it across the whole list without using `for` loops.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the column names of the data.frames in that list but their names, i.e., `names(list)`. I suggest iterating over these names:

```
volc = function(inputname){
  ggplot(list[[inputname]], aes(logFC, negLogPval)) + 
  geom_point()
  ggsave(paste0("Volcano_", inputname, ".png"), device = "png")
}

for (x in names(list)) volc(x)
```

Comment: Ah I see. the `names(list)` was applying the `names()` function to the individual data tables in the list, not to the list itself. 
Is there a similar way to do this using `lapply` rather than a `for` loop? I usually use `lapply` as I prefer the syntax, but perhaps `for` is just easier in this circumstance.

Comment: A `for` loop is the appropriate construct if you call a function purely for side effects as you do here.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the terminology, but how is this example using it for the side effects? The `ggplot` is called for its function of drawing a plot, and the `names()` is called for its function of providing the names of items in a list. Right? I am new to coding so maybe side effects has a different meaning to what I am used to?

Comment: Saving files and drawing plots are side effects as opposed to returning a value.

Comment: Hmm ok, that doesn't seem obvious, but thanks.

Also I finally tried to run your version to see if it worked well as the Map() version by Tommy, but it came back with the following error:
`Error in list[[inputname]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`
EDIT: nevermind, I solved it myself almost as soon as I posted, I forgot to rename "list" to my actual listname.

Comment: It is just what I have been using until now, perhaps you are right and for is better in this situation